# MVC.NET: How to update UI on event trigger in backend ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, razor, signalr

I want to update the browser UI on the event at controller level, such as some service is updating the database and if database gets updates then, user should get notified about it.

I don't want that browser should keep pinging to server after some seconds. 
If you can share some link of working example it'll be helpful. 
I read about SignalR but not sure how to use it. 
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

options:
1. you can write a javascript script to roll polling a mvc action.
2. you can use SignalR ,to send a message from backend with websocket http://www.asp.net/signalr